# Execute function inside view SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL function and i need to execute it inside SQL view.

any suggestion..

Comment: Search for `Inline functions`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
create view dbo.ViewName
as
select
dbo.Function(parameter)
from dbo.TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW myview AS
SELECT  *
FROM    GetValueOfItem() AS schedule
GO

SELECT  * FROM myview
```