# Returning a count of records in a view from a T-SQL function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in SQL Server which lists sections in a report.  There are three fields, a SectionID (numeric autonumber primary key), SectionTitle (title for the section on the report) and SourceView (name of the view in the local db which returns the records for the report).

What I need is a view which has these three columns plus a fourth column which shows the number of records returned by the 'SourceView'. 
Something like:

```
CREATE myView AS

SELECT
  SectionID,
  SectionTitle,
  SourceView,
  myFunction(SourceView) AS RowsInView
FROM
  tblBaseData
```

I thought this would be simple to achieve by writing a function to take in the view name and return the number of rows.  My original plan was to build some dynamic SQL in the body of the function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION myFunction(@ViewName VARCHAR) RETURNS INT AS

BEGIN

  DECLARE @RowCount INT
  DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(200)
  SET @SQL = 'SET @RowCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + @ViewName + ')'
  EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
  RETURN ISNULL(@RowCount, 0)

END
```

However, you can't use EXEC within a function so you can't run dynamic SQL, you can't use EXEC to run a procedure which returns a value, and you can't query the system objects because - although this will work for tables - it won't work for views.

I have tried the following without success:

[How to get the row count for views from a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809263/how-to-get-the-row-count-for-views-from-a-database)

[Execute function inside view SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923575/execute-function-inside-view-sql-server)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188655.aspx

[Create a function for counting rows from any table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25793020/create-a-function-for-counting-rows-from-any-table)

I am trying to get a view working because I need to display the results on a web-page with current record counts, otherwise I would build a table and refresh the data periodically,

I assume that I'm just using the wrong approach to this problem.  Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: The fundamental answer to this - provided by strickt01 below, is that you can replace views with procedures which return table variables.  This works both in reporting services and in web methods - so, problem solved.  Thanks all for help and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather clumsy but using a procedure rather than a view would get round the problems you have addressed in your question:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetViewRowCounts
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sectionId int, @title varchar(50), @view varchar(50)
    DECLARE @tbl_view_counts TABLE (section_id int not null,
                                    title varchar(50) not null,
                                    view_name  varchar(50) not null,
                                    view_count int not null)
    DECLARE @RowCount INT
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(200), @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(100)

    DECLARE c_vws CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
     SELECT
    SectionID,
    SectionTitle,
    SourceView
    FROM
    tblBaseData

    OPEN c_vws 

    FETCH NEXT FROM c_vws INTO @sectionId, @title, @view

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
         SET @ParmDefinition = N'@RowCountOUT int OUTPUT';
         SET @SQL = N'SELECT @RowCountOUT = COUNT(*) FROM ' + @view

         EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @ParmDefinition, @RowCountOUT=@RowCount OUTPUT;

         INSERT @tbl_view_counts
         VALUES (@sectionId, @title, @view, @RowCount)

         FETCH NEXT FROM c_vws INTO @sectionId, @title, @view
    END

    CLOSE c_vws
    DEALLOCATE c_vws

    SELECT * FROM @tbl_view_counts
END
```

Comment: This gives me a table variable but I can't see a way of then making the contents of the variable available to a view .... which I need for a reporting services report and for a web method which feeds a web page.  Unless I am missing something obvious (which is entirely possible) I still can't get at the contents of the table variable?

Comment: The stored procedure returns a table. You can select a stored procedure (as opposed to a view) as a data source for a reporting services report. Similarly you can execute the stored procedure within your web method as opposed to selecting from a view - they both return the same thing (i.e. a table).

Comment: This looks like the right kind of solution, but when I try the procedure and execute it - expecting a list of records - I get:  Msg 214, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_executesql, Line 1
Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.

Comment: `sp_executesql` expects nvarchar rather than varchar. I have amended my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks.  That solved that problem, but now when the procedure runs there is a repeating error about the scalar variable @RowCount not being declared.  Are we allowed to run a "set" command using sp_executesql ?

Comment: I'd just used the code from the question in that section. `sp_executesql` runs in its own batch and does not have access to variables in the stored procedure. However you can get round that using `OUTPUT`variables. Have amended the answer accordingly - and this time I've actually tested it runs!

Comment: All working.  Thanks for your time and help.  Now to wire this up into MSRS and the Web Methods.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the count back without having to use a function or know the name of the view:

```
CREATE myView AS

SELECT
  SectionID,
  SectionTitle,
  SourceView,
  COUNT(*) OVER() AS RowsInView
FROM
  tblBaseData
```

**EDIT:** Apologies, I misread your initial post. I agree that a stored procedure is probably the best way to go, but if you wanted to continue with a view approach, you could have a "lookup" view, like this:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.ViewCounts
AS

SELECT  'SourceView1' AS SourceViewName, 
        COUNT(*) OVER () AS RowsInView
FROM SourceView1
UNION
SELECT  'SourceView2' AS SourceViewName, 
        COUNT(*) OVER () AS RowsInView
FROM SourceView2

-- etc...
```

Then join back onto it in your original view to get the count this way:

```
CREATE myView AS

SELECT
  t.SectionID,
  t.SectionTitle,
  t.SourceView,
  vc.RowsInView
FROM
  tblBaseData t
JOIN dbo.ViewCounts vc ON vc.SourceViewName = t.SourceView
```

It's a very dirty approach (and the ViewCounts view will need manually updating if you add new views), but could solve your problem if you absolutely need to persist with a view.

Comment: This gives me an error in Management Studio with the "ORDER BY" clause, to be clear though I am not trying to count the rows in 'myView', I am trying to return the number of rows in the view named in the 'SourceView' field - apologies if this was not clear from my original question.

Comment: Apologies, my fault. I think I've fixed the original error (it works for me on SQL Server 2014) and I've added a new approach to consider. It's a bit dirty though :)

Comment: Thanks for this, and I agree it would provide the record count, but I can't implement a solution which needs to be edited each time a view is added into tblBaseData - any solution has to work irrespective of changes to the records in tblBaseData.